# How to implement an Authentication in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an application with angularJS and php on backend ,I want to implement authentication in my application, and I tried the code pasted below, but it doesn't generates any error, any message and when I try to put a username and password I go to the view'admin"whatever the user I enter, it means that it doesn't check the user and password. In the database of table 'client', I have : NomClient and mdp(password).

login.html

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
<div class="list list-inset" >
<label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="nom" required="" ng-model="NomClient"> 
</label> 
<label class="item item-input">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="mdp"> 
</label> 
    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>       
 </ion-content>
```

app.js

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope,$state,$http){
  $scope.submit= function(){
 const url = 'http://localhost/deb/login.php';
const postBody = {
    NomClient: $scope.NomClient,
    mdp: $scope.mdp
};

$http.post(url, postBody).then(data => {
   $location.path('/admin');
});
```

};

login.php

```
 <?php  

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tem");  


$response['status'] = 0;
$response['message'] = '';
$NomClient=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->NomClient);
$mdp=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->mdp);


$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE NomClient = "'.$NomClient.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'"';


if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    $response['status'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    echo jsone_encode($response);exit;
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rowcount>0){
    $response['status'] = 1;
    $response['message'] = 'Login successful';
}
else{
    $response['status'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid username of password';
}

echo json_encode($response);exit;
 ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not sending any data to your PHP login handler. Your current submit function in AngularJS is making a get request instead of post.

Your `$scope.submit` function should look something like this (this is not a preferred method, but probably the simplest one given your current setup):

**app.js**

```
$scope.submit = function () {

    const url = 'http://localhost/deb/login.php';
    const postBody = {
        NomClient: $scope.NomClient,
        mdp: $scope.mdp
    };

    $http.post(url, postBody).then(data => {
        // do whatever you need with the login data (token?)
    });

};
```

Second, where if your PHP script getting the `POST` data from?

You need to include something along these lines at the beginning of your PHP script to retrieve the `POST` data.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: Thank you, I did what you syggested and I edit the code, but still having no result

Comment: Can you provide some error logs or at least specify where you are getting stuck?

Comment: I have no error, when I expect the code,and also no message, when I click on submit, nothing change and I still in the same page

Comment: Of course, you are not doing anything in your `submit` function to change a page or change the UI. Have a look at the Chrome developer console if your login request is coming through.

Comment: I checked the console, I have just this message : This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more information

Comment: I thinsk, I have to try to go to other view if the username and password are true!!! but I m beginner can you please help me

Comment: You should read some basic tutorial about JavaScript, AngularJS, PHP, debugging, etc. This is all quite basic stuff and there are thousands of tutorials online. It is absolutely out of the scope of any StackOverflow question to teach you the basics of software development.